# Allocating datastore long ID's - but segmented so different Kinds have different ranges

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

My program has 3 kinds that are closely related and I want to be able to store and manipulate their long id's interchangeably, e.g. I might have an array of long id's that can be for any of the 3 Kind's.

Using [the allocateIds API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) I can allocate the ID's for the 3 kinds in the same namespace, but I also sometimes need to be able to tell which Kind one of these id's referred to (e.g. in order to do a datastore operation on the right Kind).

I understand that the 'normal' way to this is to store the whole Key type, rather then just the long id, but there will be a huge number of these - it will be more efficient if I can just use 'long' values rather then Key values.

So, I'd like to be able to segment the ID ranges, so I can call a simple function with an ID and it will tell me which of the 3 Kind's the ID is for.

(I'm using Java, but I don't think that matters.)

Comment: In the past I had come across this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/_I7KW2X02aI

Might help. If not let me delete the comment.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks.  I note that the assertion that we are charged for each ID allocation - if true, that would preclude one of the options I outline below.

Answer (score 0):

**Allocate my own ID's**

I guess the most straight-forward way to do this is to simply allocate my own ID's.  I believe that, in order to allocate sequential ID's, I would need to do an extra datastore write for every allocation (to track the allocations), or get into some complicated system of pre-allocating ranges of ID's to each live instance.  This sounds like a bad idea.

So I could generate random 54 bit ID's - reserving 2 bits to use as flags to indicate the type.  But it is my understand that random or hash allocation dramatically reduces the number of allocations that can be made safely.  The Internet tells me that the chance of a collision is approximately k^2 / 2N, where k is number of allocations and N is the size of the allocation space.  So, if I'm willing to accept 0.1% chance of collision then k=sqrt(2*2^54/1000) = ~1.9 million.  Since I really have no idea how many entities I will need to store, this is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

**Reserve some bits in the Long ID to indicate the Kind**

Another solution would be to use 2 bits of the long value as flags to indicate the type.  The easiest way to do this would be to take advantage of the fact that the allocator now only uses the low 56 bits of a long.  So I could use the high bits as flags to indicate the Kind.  The problem with that solution is that I lose the ability to manipulate these numbers in javascript - the reason for the 56 bit limit in the first place.

An alternative to this - to maintain the option of manipulating these numbers in js - is to use allocateIdRange and pre-allocate (and throw away) the ID ranges corresponding to bits 54 and 55.  Actually, I could use any bits, but specifying the ID ranges is much easier if I use the high bits.

But I know little of how the datastore and how the allocator actually work, so I don't know if this 'pre-allocate and discard' technique is a good idea.